# Adding Common class for different blackberry application

Tags: java, blackberry

I have written a common class which I want to use in separate Blackberry applications. This class is not in a separate project but just at a common location and I have linked the path of the common class in Java Build Path. I have added same common path to both of my BB applications and they builds and installs without any problem. When I run one application, it start running but when I run the other application, it gives error message "class xxx multiply defined" error and exits.

Any idea what is going wrong here. Thanks in advance

Regards,
Braj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All applications in RIM OS run under one instance of Java Virtual Machine. And therefore it is allowed only one class with particular full qualified name. Adding another class with the same name will lead to failure upon running both of these classes.

There is a library thing, supported in RIM OS, but I do not recommend to use libraries in your project, unless it is very necessary.

It is because if you have several apps with the same library, but with different versions of libraries you may get the same error you reported in your question. And it is hard to manage libraries when you have many applications which use these libraries.

I recommend to copy source code of your library to the project you are working on. Copy via refactoring, to change all full qualified names of classes included in that library.

Comment: Thanks for reply Refael. I can copy same source to each project, however the problem is, if I have to make changes to this common code, I have to do the same changes to all instances of the code in all different projects. Is there anyway to have a common file and use it in different projects?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no easy and straight way. RIM BB IDE requires source files to be added to the current project either to the dependent library project.

Comment: obviously, the problem is a result of RIM's design, but the proposal to just copy files into multiple projects is just replacing one maintenance nightmare with another

Answer (score 2):

BlackBerry doesn't work as other Java platforms. In BB Java, you can't have two classes with the same full qualified name, even if they live in different projects.

You'll have to rename one of them (either change the class name or the package name) for it to work.

In fact, the only platform where I have seen this restriction is BB. It is a real pain in the ass since you can't reuse a jar library in different projects without renaming it.

UPDATE:
This is the official article on the topic:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Application-throws-quot-multiply-defined-quot-error-at-start-up/ta-p/501498

Comment: I think this statement, `In BB Java, you can't have two classes with the same full qualified name, even if they live in different projects.` isn't true, if you don't use persistent classes. I have just built two demo applications, both of the application have one class named `mypackage.MyScreen`, and both of the application are running successfully at the same time.

Comment: @Rupak Maybe you are running each one in a different simulator? You can refer to the article I linked. It is one of the most common issues for new BB devs (me too, long time ago). And sometimes it is not even clear why it happens (i.e.: trying to import zxing which is already included in recent releases)

Comment: Okay, I will read the article. But FYI I'm running both of my application in same simulator. Though I'm running those apps in BB 9930 Simulator, BlackBerry JRE 7.0, I think I have used some of my reusable code without modifying package structure in more than one application simultaneously in much older devices (maybe on devices running OS 4.2+). But also I got the error `multiply defined` when I tried to use more than one class with same qualified name, and they had implemented Persistable interface.

Comment: But, just to be clear on what RIM recommends (in the link Mister Smith provides) ... move the *common* class into a *library* project, and then use the library in as many different apps as you like.

Comment: @Smith: I agree with Rupak. I have common class in BB and it works perfectly fine on all the devices I have tried so far. The problem is with Persistent class, which cannot be shared as full qualified names. I think I can use Persistent class in common code if I put them in a separate library and use library in different applications

Comment: @bsengar Which OS version are you targeting? In older OSes, I'm almost sure the error shows for regular classes as well. Maybe the thing has changed in newer OSes? I'll test if I find some time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for replying. I have created a common library and put common code in that. Now I can use this library in different applications without any problem.
However, when I install my applications using BB desktop Manager, the library appears as part of first application but not in second application. I assume it is because, second application realizes that the library is already been included so doesn't need to include it again.

Comment: if you have further questions, please **edit** the original question, or post a new one.  thanks.